# hide option value in Bootstrap select for certain devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap select menu for a "state" form field. On larger devices, I have labels for each dropdown but on smaller devices, they are hidden. So in order for the smaller devices to know what the menu is for, I have the word "state" as the first dropdown option.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="textinput">*State</label>
<div class="col-xs-5 col-lg-3">
<select id="state" class="form-control" name="state">
<option value="State">State</option>
<option value="AA">AA</option>...
```

Is there a better way to include the word "state" without it being an option value? Either way, how can I have it show for smaller devices, but remain hidden for larger devices (where the label will show)?

Thanks

Comment: you may want to check out dropdowns in bootstrap. I'm not sure what you want the state option to do instead but if you want users to then be able to choose a state, that's your answer. Multilevel dropdown. Plus you are assured mobile adaptability.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a media query to define the screensize:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
}
```

Then target whatever you didn't want to show within the CSS?

Comment: I tried that. It doesn't work, though.

<option value="" class="mobile-only">State</option>

and @media (min-width: 991px) {.mobile-only {display:none}}

Comment: Hey, within the media query you have to re-define the class you are targeting.